# Javascript - Serialize array to send to controller

Tags: javascript, post, serialization, controller

I've this kind of array in javascript :

`var myArray = [5,15,20,6]`

I just want to serialize it so I can pass it to my controller.

I tried `$(myArray).serializeArray()` but it returns an empty array

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: you could just do `JSON.stringify(myArray)`

Comment: Hmm, if I use JSON.stringify, my URL will be something like `utilisateurs/delete/%5B%225%22,%224%22,%222%22,%223%22,%221%22%5D`

Comment: so you send your array as an get parameter?

Comment: If you want to serialize then you have to use dictionary

Comment: In fact I just want to call a route from my controller and be able to retrieve from it my table which I send to it in javascript. So it seems to me that the best way for that is to serialize?